Is it safe to call lua function again in a c++ funciton called by lua?
For example (pseudoc code):
//c++
void foo() {
  // call lua function bar
  luapcall(bar,...
}

//binding code
export c_foo...

//lua
function bar() return nil

c_foo()

In this case, will lua stack be broken and lead to crash?

Yes it's safe, this happens all the time. Think about all of the STL functions that accept Lua callbacks.
